# implementing java interface with scala class - type issue

Tags: scala

Why on earth won't this compile? Scala 2.8.0RC3:

Java

```
public interface X {
    void logClick(long ts, int cId, String s, double c);
}
```

Scala

```
class Y extends X {
  def logClick(ts: Long, cId: Int,sid: java.lang.String,c: Double) : Unit = {
  ...
  }
}
```

Error

```
class Y needs to be abstract, since method logClick in trait X of type
(ts: Long,cId: Int,s: java.lang.String,c: Double)Unit is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You need to add `override` before the definition of `logClick` in `class Y`.</strike>

```
class Y extends X {
  override def logClick(ts: Long, cId: Int,sid: java.lang.String,c: Double) : Unit = {
  ...
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

For the reason Daniel said below, you don't even need to add `override` before the method. Your code is right as it is.

Comment: @paintcan, just tested. It works here. What version of Scala are you using?

Comment: version is in post, but since you say this worked for you we're going to try to reproduce the issue in a project with all extraneous crap removed

Comment: seems like there was an aliasing issue due to an import of java.lang.Double. whoops

Comment: You don't really need `override` when the method being overridden is abstract.